# Jquery .css('opacity', '0') not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I've been trying something out but cant make it to work.

Basically I have a bunch of `<li>` that has a hidden `<div class="overlay">`in it that would appear if the `<li>` was clicked. No problem displaying it, but somehow I'm having troubles making it disappear.

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NP5YA/

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to prevent event buble up the DOM tree so use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().css('opacity','0');
    $(this).parent().css('z-index','-999');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NP5YA/10/)

Comment: I see! That's why it was working with other css properties... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are still clicking in your li and running your function twice.
So basically it disappears and reappears. I use this when that happens.

```
$('#selection li').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).find('.overlay').css('opacity','1');
    $(this).find('.overlay').css('z-index','9999');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('opacity','0');
    $(this).parent().css('z-index','-999');
});
```

Comment: I use this because sometimes e.stopPropagation() can cause problems with other code I do want to run. This is more finite and can get you out of a jam.

Comment: I will keep it in mind next time I encounter this. I'll be using stopPropagation for now cause what Im tryna do is very simple. Thanks a lot!