# Align div to center of page overlapping a table tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I want a form displayed using DIV on center of a page. And when the form is displayed the background page should be disabled. This is my CSS:

```
.formLayout {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: solid 1px #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;       
}

.formLayout Label, .formLayout TextBox {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.formLayout label {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

This is my markup:

```
<div class="formLayout">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter the Load Code:"></asp:Label> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="inputLoadCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
          &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
          &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
            &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
          &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
          &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</div>
<table cellspacing="2" id="Components" width="100%">.........
```

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011406/jquery-cssopacity-0-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<div id="dv-modal">
        <div id="dv-bg"></div>
        <div id="dv-form"></div>
    </div>
```

And the css:

```
        #dv-modal
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index:1000;
        }

        #dv-bg
        {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #dv-form
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: gray;

            /*CENTER ON THE SCREEN*/
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -50x;
            margin-top: -50px;
        }
```

This will block any content behind...

Comment: What will the dv-modal class do?

Comment: It's just a wrapper to hold the form and background still on a fixed position. And on top of everything.